# Plot a shape on graph in Pgfplots latex

Tags: pgfplots

I have a graph in Pgfplots in latex and would like to add four triangles with their vertices at {(0,2) (4,0) and a given point on the blue line} {(0,2) (4,0) and a given point at the red line}
And is it possible for the triangles to be different colors and be a little transparent?

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{-4-x/2};
\addlegendentry{$-4-x/2$}
%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {8-x/2};
\addlegendentry{$8-x/2$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible methods, one of them is shown below.

Note the use of `axis cs` in the coordinates. The purpose of that is to declare that the coordinates should be interpreted as `axis` coordinates, which is not otherwise assumed. *Unless* you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or a newer version), then axis coordinates is assumed, so the `axis cs:` prefix is not needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={ % not really necessary, just for convenience
    f(\x) = -4 - \x/2;
    g(\x) = 8 - \x/2;
    }
    ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=2, % it's a straight line, 2 points are enough
    color=red,
]
{f(x)};
\addlegendentry{$-4-x/2$}
%Here the blue parabola is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=2, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {g(x)};
\addlegendentry{$8-x/2$}

% define named coordinates 
\coordinate (a) at (axis cs:0,2);
\coordinate (b) at (axis cs:4,0);

% create filled triangles
\fill [red,opacity=0.5] (a) -- (b) -- (axis cs:0,{f(0)}) -- cycle;
\fill [blue,opacity=0.5] (a) -- (b) -- (axis cs:0,{g(0)}) -- cycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```